# What does the word 「どいとれっ」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

After a guy having watched his friend poorly jump to the ground, he said the following sentence.

> けっ　へたっくそめ　パラシュートってのはだな　ええい　**どいとれっ。**

**Other questions**

1. Is there any meaning for the word 「けっ」 at the beginning of the sentence?
2. Is the particle 「め」 just used for emphasizing the word 「くそ」?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify a little,

「どい**とれ**っ」 in Western Japan

＝

「どい**てろ**っ」 in Eastern Japan

＝

「どい**ていろ**」 in the dictionary form

「退{ど}く」 means "to move out of the way", "to step aside", "to get out", etc.

**「どいとれっ」, therefore, means "Step aside (and stay there)!"** because it contains 「いる/いろ」 in it.

> 1) Is there any meaning for the word 「けっ」at the beginning of the sentence?

A little bit, yes.  It is an intejection of contempt.

> 2) Is the particle 「め」 just used for emphasizing the word 「くそ」?

Yes, but the word here is 「へたっくそ」 and not 「くそ」.